# Google Analytics Custom Reporting

Tags: google-analytics

I have tracked two event values customReport1 and CustomReport 2 using GA event tracking and I want to make a custom report with the event value such that customReport3(value)=[CustomReport 2(value)-customReport1(value)] insdie the GA report

is there a way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently there is not a way to perform operations on the data such as `Event value 1` - (minus) `Event value 2`.  You may be better off exporting the data as CSV and running that report through Excel or Google Docs.

That or roll your own custom reporting tool that pulls the data in through the [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataGettingStarted.html).